# ListPlot will not plot my two dimensional array

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, data

I am working in an experimental data analysis, the equipment I used handed me the data in txt. format, to import to Mathematica I used the following:

```
data = Import[
   "/Users/gustavocustodio/Downloads/debyescherrertable.txt"];

xrdata = Partition[StringSplit[data], 2]
```

which does give me the list of pairs I wanted, but I cannot plot this, I tried `ListPlot`, but it only shows and empty plot.

My .txt file has this form[image]

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this:

```
  data= Import["/Users/gustavocustodio/Downloads/debyescherrertable.txt","TSV"]/. 
      s_String :> ToExpression[s];
```

This will get rid of strings. You can do the partition if you need it. I don't have access to your data

Comment: I tried it, Mathematica says it is not a valid format. I edited my question to show my data. Thanks

Comment: But I did not used the TSV option, nevertheless I used the last `s_String :> ToExpression[s];`and it worked, can you explain why does it works and it did not before?

Comment: It's with how the strings are placed. You can import as a dat and TSV and analyze.